# Does Yii use Singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, yii, singleton

In `Yii` I can do:

```
$model = ModelName::model();
```

I can call it from **anywhere** and it will always return **same instance**.

So can I decide that `Yii` use `Singleton` pattern?

Only difference what I see is that `__construct`, `__clone`, `__wakeup` not protected.

Comment: So what are your doubts to ask question if it's singleton, when from your explanation it seems to be?

Comment: I think it is a good question. Just for the sake of clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, YII application object is a singleton. If you see Yii entry file ie, index.php, you can find the statement

```
   Yii::createWebApplication($configFile)->run();
```

This is the state which creates the instance for your application .

1. Yii is a class and it extends YiiBase.

   ```
      class Yii extends YiiBase{}
   ```
2. createWebApplication() is a static functin in the class YiiBase. This function returns the object of `CWebApplication` class.

   ```
   public static function createWebApplication($config=null)
   {
        return self::createApplication('CWebApplication',$config);
   }
   ```
3. `createAppliction('CWebApplication',$config)`  creates the object of `CWebApplication` and return that object.

Now, this Application singleton will be accessed anywhere in your application with `Yii::app()`.

To check more

```
    <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(Yii::app());
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

Coming to model, YII also impliments singleton pattern for Active records Model.

1. Go to yii/framework/yiilite.php.
2. Find the `CActiveRecord` abstract class, and search for **function model()**

   ```
   public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
   {
       if (isset(self::$_models[$className]))
           return self::$_models[$className];
       else
       {
           $model = self::$_models[$className] = new $className(null);
           $model->attachBehaviors($model->behaviors());
           return $model;
       }
   }
   ```

Understand this line

```
    if(isset(self::$_models[$className]))
        return self::$_models[$className];
```

May be this will give you more info.

Comment: What about `Model object`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a singletone in this case but it makes sense when use it with finder methods (`ModelName::model()->find($condition, $params),ModelName::model()->findAll($condition, $params) ...etc`) the reason why there is no protected in constructor is we need to create instance via the keyword 'new' `new ModelName` most of time to create an instance with attributes not already set you can see this in create controller action.

Comment: But can we call it `Singleton` if we have possibility to write `new ModelName`? From `Wiki`: singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the Instantiation of a class to one object.